# can no redirect to area in main program

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I cant going to another area when I'm in the main program.

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: /<controller>/

        public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {

            return RedirectToAction("temping","home",new { area = nameof(Areas.Admin) });
        }

    }
}
```

this is my home controller in main .and I'm needing to going to admin area with URL admin/home/temping/ but this code gives me this URL :`https://localhost:44339/home/temping?area=Admin`

my route is :

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "AdminArea",
                template: "{area:exists}/{controller=home}/{action=index}/{id?}");
```

and in the admin area, I have one controller with home name

```
[Area(nameof(Admin))]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ViewResult Index() => View(data);
        public string temping() => "hiiii";
    }
```

can any body help me?

Comment: your MapRoute for AdminArea should be before default route

Comment: The route for AdminArea should *be* the default route. You don't need both, as the `{area:exists}` portion allows routes with or without the area component.